# unexpected error in fragment when orientation changes

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use **Master details/flow** template and I want to refresh the **fragments A** when the value of the **fragments B** is changed , my code is :

```
Fragment frg = null;
frg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ouvagedisplay_list);
final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
```

After tha value of the **fragments B** is changed the **fragments A** is refreshed but when the orientation of the screen changes (landscape to portrait) or (portrait to landscape ) i get this error  unexpected error .

Comment: Pls post your crash log

Comment: I have a problem with the emulator eclipse adt when I change the orientation with Left Ctrl + F12 the emulator is oriented but the display remains the same , So I was forced to test it with my tablet.